# Why won't my video play?

Tags: html, video, youtube

.Why won't my video play? Before, when I was using a  tag, the video would show "no video with supported format and MIME type found". When I use the `<iframe>` tag it shows a blank square.Here is the code...

[image]

```
   <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://youtu.be/0vwNEc-lL2c" controls></iframe>
```

...and here is what the site shows...

[image]

Any help greatly appreciated!
NW

Comment: Please edit your post and add the code (and not image of code).

Comment: (1) If you're paid to do this, at least use correct spelling like **website** not websight... (2) `iframe` does not have a _controls_ command so that is causing error (loading stops). (3) Video Tag expects link to a **video file** not some website **page** that has text, pictures etc.. (4) If the video is on Youtube then use `iframe` with link like `https://www.youtube.com/embed/` + `videoID`, here the Youtube ID is `0vwNEc-lL2c`. See @SeppeDev's correct Answer.

Comment: I am not paid to do this. I just started studying a couple months ago. I'm doing "prework" for a bootcamp. Thank you for the help though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you add the code provided by youtube itself?

```
   <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0vwNEc-lL2c" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: @NathanW Can you please accept the answer if this solved your problem? (The checkmark under the arrows)